# File.Transfer in cordova Cannot read property 'lengthComputable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I need to download one file ,

I get the following error,

**Cannot read property 'lengthComputable' of undefined** - this error is from filetransfer.js

This is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            var uri = encodeURI("https://www.yyy.com/aspl.bak");
            var filePath = "oa.apk";
            fileTransfer.download(
                uri,
                filePath,
                function (entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
                },
                false,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: you are trying to get "lengthComputable" of the undefined. Check where you are trying to read "lengthComputable" property in file and check it is initialised or not.

Comment: it is generated automatically when we run the app, its in built

Comment: anyone knows the local path to save download file while testing in ripple emulator?

Answer (score 0):

The function:

```
function uploadPics(images, label) {
        //console.log("Ok, going to upload "+images.length+" images.");
        var defs = [];

        images.forEach(function(i) {
            //console.log('processing '+i);
            var def = $.Deferred();

            function win(r) {
                if($.trim(r.response) === "0") {
                    console.error("this one failed");
                    def.resolve(0);
                } else {
                    def.resolve(1);
                }
            }

            function fail(error) {
                console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
                def.resolve(0);
            }

            var uri = encodeURI("http://websiter.com.br/mobile/receive.php");

            var options = {
                chunkedMode: false,
                fileKey: "file",
                fileName: label[i.substr(i.lastIndexOf('/')+1)],
                //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
                params: {
                    method: "photos"
                }
            };

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(i, uri, win, fail, options);
            defs.push(def.promise());
        });

        $.when.apply($, defs).then(function() {
            console.dir(arguments);
        });

    }
```

The call:

```
var images = [ url_of_image ];
var label = [];
label[url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)] = 'IMAGE LABEL';

uploadPics(images, label);
```

This working for me!